# GeoTIFF files in ImageJ

Tags: imagej, geotiff

I am trying to open GeoTIFF file in ImageJ. It is opened as blank black image. But I want the view as its JPEG converted image. Please If anyone can help me. I want to process that image for Oil Spill Detection.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [Fiji distribution](http://fiji.sc/Downloads) of ImageJ. It includes the [Bio-Formats importer](http://imagej.net/Bio-Formats) which supports a huge number of image formats. It looks like it has support for [GeoTIFF tags](http://downloads.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/5.0.6/api/com/sun/media/imageio/plugins/tiff/GeoTIFFTagSet.html), as well.

Also, sometimes images "look" black but aren't truly. See [this FAQ entry](http://imagej.net/FAQ#The_image_I_loaded_is_displayed_all_black.21_But_it_is_not_black.21).